# Initial data creation fails with data migration

Tags: python, django

It's my intent to create some initial model instances through a data migration with some JSON data. Upon calling `json.load()` on the JSON file, I'm iterating over each dictionary and its keys. Any key with white space is supposed to be replaced with a new string containing underscores. This is being done to unpack the dictionary when creating an model instance with `Model.create()`.

What should be refactored to get the expected result?

(Note: All JSON object keys contain white space)

**Actual outcome:** Not all keys that have white space get replaced with new strings that contain underscores.

**Expected outcome:** All keys that have white space get replaced with new strings that contain underscores.

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    image_filename = models.ImageField()
    category_type= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    current_condition = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
#data migration

# Generated by Django 2.2.7 on 2019-11-30 23:21
import json
from django.db import migrations

def create_items(apps, schema_editor):
    Item = apps.get_model('items', 'Item')
    with open('my_file', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        uploaded_item_data = json.load(data_file)
        for item_dict in uploaded_minerals_data:
            item_name_data = item_dict.keys()
            for name in item_name_data:
                if " " in name:
                    value = item_dict.pop(name)
                    new_name = name.replace(" ", "_")
                    item_dict[new_name] = value
                else:
                    continue
            Item.objects.create(**mineral_dict)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('items', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_minerals)
    ]
```

Comment: Can you share the data file? Please see: [mcve]. The `else: continue` in the loop is unnecessary, by the way. The way you're iterating over the dictionary is also unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of [unicode space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs).

You can solve this problem with [isspace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isspace.asp) method or regular expression with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) like this:

```py
import re
test_string = "test string"
out1 = re.sub('\s','_', test_string)
print(out1)

out2 = str().join(['_' if x.isspace() else x for x in test_string])
print(out2)
```